# d3 problema con el borde del chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

actualmente tengo un problema, estoy usando D3 para graficar datos, el problema es que uso bordes redondeados y cuando los valores son pequeños tengo un efecto 'oreja' en mi chart

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

codigo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
              const rx = 30;
              const ry = 30;
              svg
                .selectAll(".bar")
                .data(data)
                .enter()
                .append("path")
                .attr("class", "bar")
                .attr("x", function (d) {
                  return x(d.key);
                })
                .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
                .attr("y", function (d) {
                  return y(d.value);
                })
                .attr("height", function (d) {
                  return height - y(d.value);
                })
                .attr("fill", "#206BF3")
                .attr(
                  "d",
                  (item) => `
            M${x(item.key)},${y(item.value) + ry}
            a${rx},${ry} 0 0 1 ${rx},${-ry}
            h${x.bandwidth() - 2 * rx}
            a${rx},${ry} 0 0 1 ${rx},${ry}
            v${height - y(item.value) - ry}
            h${-x.bandwidth()}Z
          `
                )
```

He visto varias preguntas y respuestas, pero no logro solucionar mi problema

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, Anderson, por favor usa el enlace [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/439684/edit) y añade tu código en formato de texto, una imagen del código solo complica la lectura

Answer (score 0):

Nunca me ha pasado creo que tu problema se debe al tamaño que utilizas en el radio (rx = 30 y ry = 30), cuando width y height son menores a este valor se crea el efecto de oreja, por lo tanto yo trataria creando una función que calculara el valor de rx y ry de forma dimanima en base al valor width y height, de modo que si el valor de width o height es menor al 30 se use rx o ry igual a width o height segun corresponda.

Si subes tu código a un [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) o una aplicacion de este estilo podria darte una ayuda más especifica.